# OpenCV and live video streaming videos from m3u8 urls

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to build an application which needs to read a video from a stream url.
I saw several lags while OpenCV shows the images, but using a fantastic url to test my application with a video, it turns out that the problem is not OpenCV is going too slow but too fast.

If I try the following code, I can see the video is reproducing at least 3x faster that it should be.

**My code:**

```
import cv2
url="http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8"
vcap = cv2.VideoCapture(url)

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = vcap.read()

    if frame is not None:
        # Display the resulting frame
        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)

        # Press q to close the video windows before it ends if you want
        if cv2.waitKey(22) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        print("Frame is None")
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
vcap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
print("Video stop")
```

**Result**

[image]

**How it should be**

[image]

Do you know a way to make openCV read the video correctly, I mean, I would like the same speed that video should be reproduced.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can get video frame rate using ```fps = video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)``` and sleep the thread for needed millis

Comment: and where do I have to put the sleep and which value?

Answer (score 3):

here it is:

```py
import cv2
import time


url = "http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8"
vcap = cv2.VideoCapture(url)
fps = vcap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
wt = 1 / fps

while True:
    start_time = time.time()
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = vcap.read()

    if frame is not None:
        # Display the resulting frame
        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

        # Press q to close the video windows before it ends if you want
        if cv2.waitKey(22) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
        dt = time.time() - start_time
        if wt - dt > 0:
            time.sleep(wt - dt)
    else:
        print("Frame is None")
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
vcap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
print("Video stop")
```

Comment: I implemented something similar but if you take a look to the video, there's still a "lag" each 10 seconds (approx) and if you try with other url videos, it doesn't work, for example, if you change the url for this: http://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/sintel/hls/playlist.m3u8 it won't work. I have tried almost everything and I think this is a weak of OpenCV that it needs to be improved. Anyway, can I ask why you put `22` inside `cv2.waitKey` I read the documentation but I still don't understand how it works.

Comment: sorry but I didn't put ```cv2.waitKey(22)``` into you code :)) it was already in yours. I found some normal explanation: cv2.waitKey() is a keyboard binding function. Its argument is the time in milliseconds. The function waits for specified milliseconds for any keyboard event. If you press any key in that time, the program continues. If 0 is passed, it waits indefinitely for a key stroke. It can also be set to detect specific key strokes like, if key a is pressed etc which we will discuss below.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick answer, did you check the lag I'm telling to you? almost each 10 seconds the lag comes :-(. Anyway, it is true your solution improves a lot my code.

Comment: Yes I had the same lags when I run the code. I think it can be because of internet connection. Maybe it cannot download the video as fast as show it. idk really. Sorry for my english :)